# One to many with foreign key in hibernate(Exception : a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
I have two Entities, Person and Address. 

public class Person{

private long personId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
-------------------

}

public class Address{

private long addressId;
private String street;
private String zipcode;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="GRANT_ID")
private Person person;
-------------------

}

SessionFactory sessionFactory= new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(person);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

The values are set for these entities from ui and will be saved in DAO using hibernate. When  I submit a form and trying save the objects getting the following error.
"org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session".
After a lot of search in the google about the issue i could not resolve the issue. If I use merge instead of save/saveorUpdate it's inserting the record into Person and only one record into Address even though i have two addresses. I have been struggling for the last 3 days i am not in a position to resolve the issue.
I am using separate sequences to generate pks for both the table.Can anyone please provide me a solution for this issue? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you show your dao and client code

Comment: Calling this method upon the form submission.     @RequestMapping(value = "/savePerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String savePerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person){  PersonDAO.savePerson(person); is my Controller method. And in my DAO getting session and saving the person as mentioned above.

Comment: see this http://srlawr.blogspot.com/2011/08/hibernate-exception-different-object.html

Comment: Not useful for this requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Hibernate is trying to select the first Entity in the list. It is shown in the hibernate query.